# Obtaining context information in Spring 3.0 Exception Handlers

Tags: java, spring, exception

I am attempting to set-up a scheme for uniformly handling exceptions in Spring.  As such, I need a way to pass context information into an `@ExceptionHandler`-annotated method, for example consider the following:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public void handleException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
    // Need access to myContext from login()
}

@RequestMapping(value = "{version}/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void login(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String version, @RequestParam("userName") String userName, @RequestParam("password") String password, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
    ...
    myContext = "Some contextual information"
    ...
    i_will_always_throw_an_exception();
}
```

Since Spring is responsible for translating a thrown exception into an invocation of `handleException()`, I am having difficulty trying to find a way to pass `myContext` to the handler.  One thought I have is creating a subclass of HttpServletRequest.  If that approach works I would have code like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public void handleException(Exception ex, MyCustomHttpServletRequest request) {
    // I now have access to the context via the following
    String myContext = request.getContext();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "{version}/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void login(MyCustomHttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String version, @RequestParam("userName") String userName, @RequestParam("password") String password, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
    ...
    myContext = "Some contextual information"
    request.setContext(myContext);
    ...
    i_will_always_throw_an_exception();
}
```

But, if I follow this approach, how do I properly use my own arbitrary sub-class of HttpServletRequest to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just put it into exception (if necessary - wrapping the original exception with the new one)?

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyContextualException.class)
public void handleException(MyContextualException ex) {
    // Need access to myContext from login()
}

@RequestMapping(value = "{version}/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void login(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String version, @RequestParam("userName") String userName, @RequestParam("password") String password, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
    ...
    myContext = "Some contextual information"
    ...
    try {
        i_will_always_throw_an_exception();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new MyContextualException(myContext, ex);
    }
}
```

An alternative approach is to pass the context as a request attribute:

```
request.setAttribute("myContext", myContext);
```

Comment: Yes, but this seems to defeat the purpose of having the convenience of @ ExceptionHandler-annotated methods.  I basically want to avoid having a bunch of @ RequestMapping-annotated methods with massive try-catch blocks.  The Spring docs suggest that the login() method above could accept multiple types of HttpServletRequests but I have yet to find any documentation on *how* to do that.

Comment: Although setting the context as an attribute is probably an OK solution.  Not particularly elegant, but should do the trick.

Comment: It turns out this is what I ended up doing to solve the problem.